# Flutter how to convert timestamp date time

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-format

I am getting date and time from store. In data base its look like this

[image]

Need to know how can I show this as DD/MM/YY

I am trying to do like this

```
    String timeString = snapshot.data[index]['lastupdate'].toString();
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(timeString);
    print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(date));
```

Its showing error of Invalid date format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this your lastupdate date is not convertime inDate thats why its showing error

```
DateTime date = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index]['lastupdate'].toDate().toString());
print(DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyy').format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function to get date from Timestamp like this:

```
readDate(Timestamp dateTime) {
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateTime.toDate().toString());
    // add DateFormat What you want. Look at the below comment example 
    //String formatedDate = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyy').format(date); 
    String formatedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(date);
    return formatedDate;
  }
```

Use the function when you want it.
For example:

```
Text(readDOB(streamSnapshot.data!["dob"]))
```

For this you should install `intl` package. [read](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)